# How do I get my desktop image into my HTML? (Not a duplicate)

Tags: html, image, src

I've looked around and all the things i've seen make it so this code should work, but for whatever reason it won't.

```
<img src="C:\Users\(your user)\Desktop\OhDangPics\ohDangbanner.jpg"/>
```

I've made a folder in netbeans with the pictures as well, but that won't work either. That's the directory for the file, but it still doesn't work

Comment: where is your site running? You can only access your lokal files if the site is run from the same local drive

Comment: Have you tried turning on the developer console in your browser and looking for error output there?

Comment: it's just on a local host right now

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (12:09:41:715 | error, network)
  at http://localhost:8383/favicon.ico

Comment: You very likely need to have a relative path to your image, unless your `html` file is in the same directory as your `Desktop` (not likely)

Comment: If `Desktop` directory is in your web root, add a `/` to the beginning of the image filename.

Comment: What is the URL of the HTML document?

Comment: its a local hosted right now

Answer (score 1):

try this code instead and replace the parenthesis with your user

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img src="C:\Users\(your user)\Desktop\OhDangPics\ohDangbanner.jpg" alt="" style="width:1000px;height:1000px;">

</body>
</html>
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It's considered best practice to keep anything to do with your project inside the same root directory. I would suggest copying your desktop image and placing it in a new directory inside your project.

Say you had a directory called *Project* which contained your `html` file, and this directory contained another called *images*, and you put your `ohDangbanner.jpg` image in there, you could then do:

```
<img src="images/ohDangbanner.jpg" alt=""/>
```